# How to embedd gridview in viewport

Tags: extjs

In extjs, I want to implement grid structure as per mentioned in [link](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/example/writer/writer.html).

So how to embed this grid structure in basic viewport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the center region of the viewport a Container, and then add the grid to that container.

```
this.viewport = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewport')[0];
this.centerRegion = this.viewport.down('[region=center]');

this.centerRegion.add(new Ext.grid.Panel({title:'Grid', columns:[{text:'col1'}]}));
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5T4/1/